# disable network adapter with wmic - access denied (Windows 7 Prof)

Tags: windows-7, wmic

I would like to disable the local network card (only one in the computer) by using this command:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

return value is 5 (access denied).
I don't know what the problem is.

The current user has admin rights (it is not actually the admin but has admin rights).
Operating system is win7 professional.

When I activate the admin account and perform this command under this admin account everything works. But I don't wont to keep the real admin account enabled. runas isn't an option also.

It seems that I'm missing a specific right to run this command. Does anyone know what to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (solved). It is not enough the user to have admin rights.
The  most important is that you must **'run as administrator'**. 
See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711425/run-as-administrator-vs-administrator-group). Right click the command prompt (or batch file) and choose '**Run as administrator**'

This solved my problem with *ReturnValue = 5*;

And one more shortcuts - instead of

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

you can use

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Wireless Network Connection" call disable
```

and for enable

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Wireless Network Connection" call enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PowerShell?

```
Disable-NetAdapter -Name 'YourNic'
```

Here is an article I wrote on [Enabling / Disabling NICs with PowerShell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-disable-netadapter.htm)

Note: You need PowerShell v 3.0.